# Mafia Wars Web Game

Tags: language-agnostic

I plan to start web app development. (Html, Css and Php) I want to make a mafia wars style game for the web. Static graphics game is played using buttons.

Its would really just be a database to store stats and a bunch of buttons.

Would this be too hard for a complete beginner to web development to take on? Would javascript even be necessary for this?

Comment: Have you ever tried playing Mafia Wars, at least?

Comment: Considering that Zygna has a full team of full time devlopers working on Mafia Wars, I'd say "yes", too much for a beginner ;)

Comment: Note that Java is *NOT* the same thing as Javascript

Comment: I'm aware that JS is NOT Java.

Comment: No reason you can't do this and it will be a great way to learn the basics of logic.  Will you be able to immediately produce a product that will scale to the level of MafiaWars, etc... probrably not.  But don't let that discourage you.

Comment: Use version control.  Learn git if you can.  Otherwise coding will be a nightmare after about 3 files.

Comment: @shorty876: lots of answers speak about JS, and your question has been edited so that now shows Javascript instead of Java... that's why I specified that.

Comment: hmm I had a space between "java" and "script" maybe caused confusion.

I'm confused what javascript would be used for in this project. Im not a pro but I would think you could just link a different web page for each button and use php to run the backend when a button is pressed to store the data from what was done.

Comment: @shorty876: well, think how painful it would be for the player if every single button that you press you'll have to wait for the server to respond and do something... JS would allow you to do some interaction on the client (or even asynchronously on the server through AJAX). Of course not all of the interaction may be done on the client (also remember that anything that happens on the client is spoofable) but for some things JS may be helpful.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah it could get painful to have to reload the page every button click. Maybe i'll write it without JS and rewrite it when I have more pratice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It would be too hard for a COMPLETE beginner to take on. Where complete beginner = just learning to program. If you have some other background (General CS knowledge, Database experience) then you could probably do it.

JavaScript doesn't sound necessary for what you are describing.

I would suggest going through a couple tutorials on web application development so that you understand the basic concepts, and then decide whether you know enough to start building your game app. Here are a couple tutorials for various development environments:

- http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.aspx
- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html
- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebApp.html

You should probably at least read through some of those to get an idea of what you should know.

Comment: Hmm Maybe I should have clarified. I have programming experience not any on the web though.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be too hard for a complete
>   beginner to take on?

I don't think so. The game hasn't been developed by a single developer, there is a team of developers behind it. That shouldn't be an issue anyway, however, it won't be that easy for a ***beginner*** to take on such website initially unless you have good understanding of various concepts including strong knowledge of the main language, javascript, html, etc.

> Would java script even be necessary
>   for this?

Possibly. Facebook has its own implementation of javascript named FBJS (Facebook JavaScript), it is more or less similar to vanilla javascript. At some stage or the other, javascript is needed to build some dynamic pages and there are certain facebook-related stuff you will need to use javascript (FBJS) for.

Comment: can I ask why are you suggesting specifically FBJS, rather than plain JS, or JQuery or any other library out there?

Comment: @nico: Because in facebook canvas application, you can not use vanilla javascript/jquery, you only have the option of FBJS. However, if your app is iframe based rather than canvas, you can use javascript/jquery in that case.

Comment: @Sarraz: Ok, I understand. I just didn't get from the question that he wanted to do it as a Facebook app! (and being an anti-Facebook person I didn't know that you had to use FBJS for Facebook apps :P)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript. Yes. However, it can be done without but it may hurt the game in the long run.

A project for a beginning? It depends how focus the programmer is. If you are using this project to learn, certainly a good place to start. However, if it is for long run serious project, I would reconsider after learning some of the basic of programming.

Comment: I really dont have a time restraint. This is a game I have dreamt of for a long time and I only really have school as a obligation.

Answer (score 0):

If you love the idea you have and want to run with it, you will learn a ton in the process. Just don't expect to have a working product in a week. Don't let feature-creep hit too hard either. Odds are you'll end up re-writing it once you have an idea of how the process goes over all. I did something similar a few years back over the course of a month and I was pretty pleased with everything I learned.

You can do it, with patience.